# Phonegap - How open 'Facebook send dialog' with the To field populated by Facebook UserId

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm currently using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4

```
var options  = {
    method: 'send',
    app_id:'262349611811256',  //Edited ID for Stackoverflow
    to: '12353404846137727'    //Edited ID for Stackoverflow
};
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(options,
    function (result) {
        alert("Posted. " + JSON.stringify(result));
      },
function (e) {
    alert("Failed: " + e);
});
```

The dialog opens but the To field isn't populated with the User.

**Is there a way to open the 'send facebook send message dialog' from Phonegap Ios/Android?**

Comment: Where did you get the user id from? Is it an app-scoped or a global one? Does it work if you call the [URL redirect version](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog#url) of the dialog directly in your browser, with the sama parameters? (You might need to specify a website URL in ap settings beforehand, so that the `redirect_uri` will be accepted.)

Comment: I'm using an app-scoped ID. 
I have a URL set in app settings. I'll try specifying the redirect_uri as well.

Comment: Yeah - even if I specify a redirect URL it doesn't work - the To field is empty.
var options  = {
                        method: 'send',
                        app_id:'262349611811256',
                        to: '12353404846137727',
                        redirect_uri: 'http://test.com'
                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a Facebook send dialogue, can only be done via the desktop app and not via mobile.